# My html document can't find my CSS Sheet

Tags: html, css

For the index file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
```

That works fine no problem here though.

The rest of my html documents are in a folder called "pages". Here though it cant find my CSS sheet. I tried

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../oliverteglhus.dk/css/stylesheet.css"/>
```

Does not work. Sorry for this noob question. It's just bugging me.

Comment: For those of us that aren't telepathic, we'd need to see the directory structure.

Comment: @Yazin i completely agree

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the rest of your documents are in a folder that is in the same directory as your index file, then you only need to go up one directory to find your CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if your *directory structure* looks like this:

```
-index.html
-pages
    page1.html
    page2.html
    etc...
-css
    stylesheet.css
```

To load the `stylesheet.css` from **CSS** folder in `page1.html`, you have to use like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css"/>
```

[Check this answer for a more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17621358/1763929)