# Google app engine subdirectory loads differently with trailing /

Tags: php, css, google-app-engine

[Edit to be a little clearer:]

I have a project hosted on Google App Engine (myappname.appspot.com)/ (myappname.com). So far so good.

There's a root level, and a subdirectory called `folder`.  The css styles for that subdirectory are in `folder/css`. (e.g. `folder/css/main.css`).

When I request `myappname.com/folder/`, the content loads correctly, including css styles. Note the trailing slash `/`.

However, when I go to `myappname.com/folder` (no trailing slash), no css is loaded.  I see in my logs a request for `css/main.css`, which does not exist.  What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's the relative link from index.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

Here's my app.yaml:

```
application: myappname
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /folder/css
  static_dir: folder/css

- url: /folder/
  script: folder/index.php

- url: /folder
  script: folder/index.php

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use absolute, not relative paths in your links. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621324/relative-path-to-css-file

Answer (score 1):

As per your edit - this should work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/myappname.com/folder/css/main.css">
```

Just fill in myappname.com with whatever yours is.

---

**Or** you could use app.yaml and add the following:

```
- url: /css
  static_dir: css/folder
```

Then change your link to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

Comment: Well, technically, yes. :) But there's a reason relative links exist.  What if I change the directory structure later? What if I host somewhere else?  I am really looking for an answer about why relative linking is working correctly in one case, and incorrectly in the other.

Comment: Hi abagshaw, Thanks for the edit. Yes, this redirects correctly.  But it assumes I do not have other subdirectories.

Comment: You mean other sub directories other than folder? Or sub directories past folder (i.e. `folder/afterfolder/afterafterfolder`)?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem hardlink your stylesheet, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

Comment: Hey @Bill, unfortunately that makes the page load without the stylesheet in both situations. I looked in the logs and as you would think, hard linking to /css/main.css tries to load a file located at /css.  It is actually in /folder/css/main.css.  The problem is, I can't figure out why requesting "folder/" successfully requests /folder/css/main.css yet "folder" requests the non-existent /css/main.css.

Comment: Can you link to /folder/css/main.css? Otherwise, another option is to use htaccess (or similar) to add trailing slashes to all pages.

Comment: If I hardlink to /folder/css/main.css, then requesting folder/ (trailing slash) fails because it tries to get folder/folder/css/main.css.

Comment: I didn't think GAE allowed .htaccess?  Pretty sure all the rules need to be in app.yaml. I'm just a newbie at writing them.

Comment: You're right, I missed it. You can use app.yaml. This post explains it: http://blog.engelke.com/2008/07/31/appengine-rewrite-rules/