# Why can't my HTML file find the CSS file?

Tags: html

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
       <link rel=“stylesheet” href=“style.css” type=“text/css”>
    </head>

    <body>

       <p>Red</p>

    </body>

    </html>
```

CSS File

```
p {
   color: red;
}
```

The two files are in the same directory and the word 'Red' will not turn red. For some reason my CSS file isn't linking to the html file.

Comment: You must use straight quotes (`'…'` or `"…"`), not curly ones (`‘…’` nor `“…”`).

Comment: The ANSWER might be duplicate but the question isn't.  If you don't know what the problem is you will never find that other answer.

Comment: See more about relative css path here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621324/relative-path-to-css-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621324/relative-path-to-css-file)

Comment: @Lance True, if someone does not know the problem he won't be able to find the other answer. Therefore, I linked it for him.

Answer (score 0):

From your browser inspect your code by press F12 or right click--> inspect

And make sure your CSS path and properties of style listed..

Answer (score 0):

Yours:

```
<link rel=“stylesheet” href=“style.css” type=“text/css”>
```

Correct:

```
 <link rel= "stylesheet" href= "style.css" type= "text/css">
```

" is right.

“ is wrong.