# CSS not loading with codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

IM trying to load some css directly within my view file, but its not working.

in my view file I have this.

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The assets folder is at the same level as `Application`

when I view source on the webpage it shows me this

`demo.example.com/assets/css/core.css`

but when i click the link to see if it's working the url becomes this...

`http://demo.example.com/admin/demo.example.com/assets/css/core.css`

not sure what I am doing wrong?  Should I be adding something to my htaccess file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set the base url in config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://demo.example.com/'`

Comment: It is recommend now to set the base url in codeigniter 3 and up versions there is a comment above the base url which should read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the `base_url()` in your  path because the webserver already knows your at `www.example.com/admin` and auto includes that.

Just use 
    `<link href="/assets/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Edit: Or actually you need to include the `http:` prefix on your base_url like wolfgang1983 said.

See this answer on CSS absolute and relative link paths. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17621358/3585500

Comment: it was the stupid http that wolfgang said.  Irritating! Thanks to you both.

Comment: ugh, so now that i've added a sub path like, demo.example.com/admin the css breaks again.  WTF am I doing wrong? apparantely its only a problem on chrome.  Firefox works fine

Comment: in my situation the url helper functions `link_tag` fixed my issues