# HTML can't link Css online in Github Pages but not locally in Linux

Tags: javascript, html, css, linux

I started to use Linux recently, when I want to edit some html files, the css file cannot be linked to the html file.

For example,
 link rel="stylesheet" href="/zixucheah331/css/index.css"

Previously, it works on my Windows 0S. 
But now it shows "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" in the console.
Any solution from professional Linux users??

Comment: "File Not Found" is pretty clear. Your URL must be wrong.

Comment: You've got the wrong URL for the CSS file. Little to do with Linux versus Windows - understand your file structure and how it relates to your URLs.

Comment: Are you running a local server or just opening the files directly in the browser? If it's the latter, then referencing root "/" won't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your style sheet is not found by your brower.

Change the href to :

```
href="css/index.css"
```

Doing that, your browser should search relatively from the path of your page.
So this will work if you have :
index.html
css/index.css

As it is likely to be the case, you will have your problem temporary fixed.

*temporary* only, as if you have pages in another structure, you will have to adapt the path - so it is not optimal :

```
index.html
event/index.html
event/super-event.html
```

in super-event, the address will be

```
href="../css/index.css"
```

More info on : [relative path to CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621324/relative-path-to-css-file)

Comment: You could also search and learn things about : how to create a vhost for your web server, and how to edit your /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Thanks it works by changing the href to : "css/index.css"