# How do I set up a main css file for all html files?

Tags: html, css, web

Instead of having to copy the css file over and over again when making a new subdirectory with a html file in it, I would like to have one css file that applies to all html files. How would I do this? I am managing my files through StackCP. My css file is in my public_html folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the way you do this is:

Step 1: Create your main.css **(It shouldn't necessarily be main.css any name would work like style.css)** file anywhere you want but it should be inside the public_html folder.

Step 2: Create your HTML files and include the link/path/URL of the CSS file in your head section of each HTML file. To do this you use the link tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
```

The rel attribute in the link tag defines what type of file it is in your case you can put stylesheet and the href attribute defines the link/path/URL to your CSS file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Content of the page -->
  </body>
</html>
```

In the end, your HTML file should something like this.

I hope It helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a relative file path to link to your CSS file from other directories. Check out [relative path to CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621324/relative-path-to-css-file) for more details on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Place

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/stylesheet.css">`

in your header.

Comment: this answer feels incomplete. The OP probably needs some understanding about what to put in the `href` attribute and why. If they copy paste this as is, obviously it won't work. :)