# Can't implement my own stylesheet with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've run into trouble using my own stylesheet while using Bootstrap. This is the beginning of my header.php (which I import in the beginning of index.php):

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="includes/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="includes/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**EDIT:**
I've found out that for some reason I can include the file if it is in the same folder by: `<link mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">`
but if I move the folder the includes folder and do as I did in the beginning, for some reason it won't import the stylesheet. Very weird...

Comment: Seems to [work as expected](https://www.codeply.com/p/WIpnDEF8F1). Are you sure `mystyle.css` is properly referenced & loaded? What does the other code look like? Is the dropdown inside a navbar or tabs?

Comment: Does the browser console (F12) show errors?

Comment: No browser error. It is definitely the connection to mystyle.css that is flawed! I'm sure I referenced it right however. I'll edit the post and show you the code!

Comment: I am using it in a navbar indeed, but I don't think this is the problem - I can't even give body attributes, so I dont think mystyle.css is included. I just don't know why.

Comment: Info on relative paths: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621324/relative-path-to-css-file

Comment: Thank you. Not sure how to 'close' the thread, but I think it's solved (for now, I'll just move the file, and I'll investigate css paths further later)

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use a more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) selector or use `!important` (less recommended).

Try setting an id for your menu, lets say `my-menu`. Then, change the selector:

```
#my-menu {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

If you don't want to use an ID, try adding `!important`:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 300px !important;
  height: 400px !imporatnt;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually did that, just made a mistake posting the post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting the file out of `includes`. I tried later putting it in the includes file again and reference it by `<link href="includes/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">`, and now it works. It might've been an spelling error. Case closed!